# Creating an XML layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My problem is I can't seem to get my menu layout to work. So far I've tried using LayoutWeight to try to get the ImageButton's to use up a certain amount of space but I cant seem to get it to work and there's a big gap in between where the first two and second two ImageButton's are.

Below is a link to a very quick wire frame of what I want the layout to look like and below that is the code I currently have, without the bottom TextView.

I'm not really sure if this is specifically a programming question, but I am looking for either useful resources regarding layouts, suggestions on what I should look in to for certain parts of the code or code that will do what I want/something very similar.

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

**Quick notes on my quick wireframe** -

I essentially want the logo to take up 10% of the vertical pixels/screen, the square images to take 35% each row, so 70% overall. and the remaining 20% to be allocated to the TextView at the bottom.

[image: img]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_hb" 
        />    
    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"        
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/imagebutton1"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/imagebutton2" 
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/imagebutton3"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/imagebutton4"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:weightSum="100"` to your main `LinearLayout` and then give its sublayouts the weight required by specifying `android:layout_weight="weight_value"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:weightSum="100">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_weight="10"/>    

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_weight="35" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" 
    android:layout_weight="35">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vI1LF.png This is what I mean is happening with the gaps between the square images, might this be a different problem to do with the images themselves? (they are 400x400px images)

Comment: Simple answer: There's no way to remove those gaps. Those gaps are a result of the "src:"-property of the ImageView. The ImageView keeps the aspect-ratio of your image while the LinLayout (containing the ImgView) is forced to a specific height by the weight-property.

Comment: Are there other ways to structure my layout that will remove the gaps? Or perhaps there's a function that I can use one image for the buttons then use areas of that image for each link, if that's possible?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8x6Wc.png This is the kind of style I'm going for, but rather than rectangle buttons, I want square ones.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is use relative layout instead of linear layout. Just drop controls you need with designer and anchor them at the right positions.
The only one problem is forcing your square vievs square. Probably you have to make your own control and override it's onMeasure() method to set height equals the width.

Comment: Could you please explain us how to give a view in a RelativeLayout a specific percentage-height like 10% / 35% etc. as wished from the author?! I guess not. So even if I don't like nested LinearLayouts the only correct solution for this "problem" is the one posted by Laksh.

Comment: This requirement is nonsense - you simply can't expect that midle part of layout will be square and will be taking 70% of screen height, while you have different devices, different screen proportions (is there a device with 7:10 screen?

Comment: In regards to the previous comment about screen sizes. I want the imagebuttons to take 70% of the screen size, then the bottom text view fills up the remaining space, however much that is. Sorry if I didn't make it clear - See my comment in Laksh's answer for an image of what it looks like with his code

Comment: Well that's true we can't guarantee that the view will always be squared. (Luckily the ImageView keeps the ratio of the image applied; btw due that there's no way of having no gap between the different images). Overall at least most of the android handsets have a 16:9 aspect-ratio so I think the LinLayout approach is better than creating a RelativeLayout for every Screensize.

Comment: If images do not need to be square use Laksh answer. If "square" is more important than "70%" use mine ;)